# Pretty-printing a datetime as a day of the week plus time in jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, jquery-plugins, pretty-print

I'm looking for a (ideally jQuery plugin) Javascript library that will let me provide datetimes formatted in whatever standard format (ISO 8601 seems to be the most commonly used among libraries that do something similar, like timeago and Prettydate), and have them transformed into strings like:

- Wednesday, 5:00pm
- Tomorrow, 9:00am
- Saturday, 11:00pm

etc.

Timezone offsets are not a concern, since the event entities (the time of which I want to pretty print like above) are only shown to a user if  they are sufficiently geographically close (within a single timezone).

Any ideas? Any and all help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Time zones are boundaries that have no respect for geography.  Hopefully your solution wouldn't send me 100 miles away (to remain in the same time zone) when the nearest event is only 5 miles away but just across the time zone boundary.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that the definition of 'geographically close' is in the same timezone as the user - this is not the case. I was just mentioning in my question that timezones are irrelevant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)

> Datejs is an open-source JavaScript
>   Date Library.
>
> Comprehensive, yet simple, stealthy
>   and fast. Datejs has passed all trials
>   and is ready to strike. Datejs doesn’t
>   just parse strings, it slices them
>   cleanly in two.

The API is clean and easy to understand, and it just works.